# SonataAdmin in Symfony3 - There are no model managers registered

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to use the command sonata:admin:generate for generating an admin from an entity, but the following error occurs every time:

`[RuntimeException]
 There are no model managers registered.`

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will take a guess but did you install SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle as described [here](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/4.x/getting_started/installation/)?

To install it, you can simply run

`composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle`

Comment: No, I didn't, I just noticed it yesterday in the late evening. Thanks for giving the correct answer though. Your guess is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem.
When i try generate admin classes i get error:

```
In AdminMaker.php line 295:
```

There are no model managers registered.

But, I have installed and activated bundles SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle in bundles.php

```
    Sonata\DatagridBundle\SonataDatagridBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

What is wrong? What is this "model manager"?
Doctrine bundle is installed and configured too...

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    # use postgresql for PostgreSQL
    # use sqlite for SQLite
    driver: 'mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'

    # only needed for MySQL
    charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

Comment: You might want to ask a new question. Btw. in your bundles, I don't see the SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle anywhere.